# Factor the Quadratic

Tags: factoring, quadratics

-16t^2+32t+20=0.
How are you supposed to find -5 and positive 1 to put in the parenthesis? -4(2t-5)(2t+1)?

Comment: Check again $-4(2t-1)(2t-3)$. It is not $-16t^2+32t +20$.

Comment: Oh sorry! Yes, thank you for pointing that out lol! BUT this is as far as I know how to solve -4(2t  ) (2t  ) I don't know how to find the missing numbers -5 and positive 1.

Comment: $-16 t^2+32t+20= -16(t^2-2t-5/4)$. Then find the 2 roots of $t^2-2t-5/4$ (which we call $a$ and $b$), and the factorization is $-16 t^2+32t+20=-16(t-a)(t-b)$ (eventually use the 16 to simplify denominators appearing from $a,b$).

Comment: I still do not understand... The only part I get is the -16(t^2-2t-5/4).

Comment: Take out a $-4$, the $4$ part because it will make the numbers smaller, the $-$ because positive coefficient of $t^2$ is more familiar. We get $-4(4t^2-8t-5)$. Now you want to factor $4t^2-8t-5$. You may be down to a more familiar problem. If there is a nice factorization, the constant terms will be $-5$ and $1$, or $5$ and $-1$.

Comment: I appreciate the help André!

Answer (score 1):

$-16t^2+32t+20=-16(t^2-2t-5/4) $. Roots of $t^2-2t-5/4$ are
$$\frac{2\pm \sqrt{4+5}}{2} = 1\pm 3/2,$$
hence 
$$-16t^2+32t+20=-16(t-(1-3/2))(t-(1+3/2))=-16(t-5/2)(t+1/2)=-4(2t-5)(2t+1)$$

Comment: Oh I get it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You know that $-4(2t-5)(2t+1)=0$.

What values of $t$ will make the above result in $0$? If we think a little, we can note that if any of the terms are being multiplied by zero, then the product is zero as well, since $c\times 0=0$ for any value of $c$.

To determine what values of $t$ would make one of the terms zero we proceed to see how each term could equal zero like so:

We note that if $(2t-5)=0$, then the entire left side of the equation would equal zero since we are multiplying terms by $0$. To solve this, we add $5$ to both sides and divide both sides by $2$ giving us $2t-5=0\implies 2t=5\implies t=\frac{5}{2}$, so this is one value of $t$ that would result in the left hand side of the equation being zero. So this is one of our solutions.

Similarly, we note that if $(2t+1)=0$, then the left hand side of the equation would equal zero. We solve for $t$ in this. We subtract $1$ from both sides and divide by $2$ giving us $2t+1=0\implies 2t=-1\implies t=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Hence the solutions of the quadratic, i.e., the values of $t$ which would make $-4(2t-5)(2t+1)=0$ are $t=\frac{5}{2}$ and $t=-\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Hey.. I understand now. I appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem. Glad to have helped.